# why do i sometimes have to create a variable before passing an object as an argument

Tags: objective-c, macos

i'm building an app in objective c for osx, and i i don't understand why i sometimes have to put an object in a variable before passing it as an argument.

usually this way of passing an argument works fine

`[object function:[[MyObject alloc]init]];`

but when i try to this in my app

`[NSApp setDelegate:[[LHUAppDelegate alloc]init]];`

i get a runtime bad access error, so i have to do this

`LHUAppDelegate* ad = [[LHUAppDelegate alloc]init];
[NSApp setDelegate:ad];`

i've had this issue on several other occasions and i never really understood why, and i can't seem to find an answer out there. any help is much appreciated

my app delegate is completely empty, and my main.c looks like this

```
#include <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#include "LHUAppDelegate.h"
#include "LHUView0.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    [NSApplication sharedApplication];

    LHUAppDelegate* ad = [[LHUAppDelegate alloc]init];
    [NSApp setDelegate:ad];

    NSWindow* w = [[NSWindow alloc]initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 600, 400) styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:YES];
    [w setTitle:@"cocoagl"];
    [w center];

    LHUView0* glv = [[LHUView0 alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 0, 0) pixelFormat:[NSOpenGLView defaultPixelFormat]];
    [w setContentView:glv];

    [w makeKeyAndOrderFront:w];

    [NSApp run];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you starting your app manually instead of using the framework-provided entry point `NSApplicationMain()`?

Comment: there are many reasons for doing that, but it's primarily because i don't want to use xib files, and `NSApplicationMain()` loads MainMenu.xib, you can read more [here](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/demystifying-nsapplication-by.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the delegate of NSApp will not retain your instance of LHUAppDelegate in the first example. Storing it in a variable in the current scope will retain it, invoking the normal ARC behavior you'd expect -- retained, and then -1 to retain when the scope completes (which is pretty much app exit in this example).

NSApp delegate is defined as:

```
@property(assign) id< NSApplicationDelegate > delegate
```

`assign` implies `__unsafe_unretained`. Delegates are often (always?) defined this way, as "setting the delegate" on an instance usually doesn't / shouldn't imply a transfer of ownership.

In your first example, the retain count of the LHUAppDelegate instance is hitting zero (and being deallocated by ARC for you) by the time the scope of `setDelegate:` completes.

Comment: but when i set the delegate, isn't it stored in `[NSApp delegate]` and therefore retained?

Comment: @haag Read again what I wrote, especially the line from the documentation about how the `@property` `delegate` is defined. It is defined with `assign` which implies `__unsafe_unretained`. When `setDelegate` is called, it's definition (of assign) tells it to *not* increase the retain count.

Comment: @haag, no. That's what is implied by the property having the `assign` attribute rather than `strong`. Delegates are not retained because that is very likely to lead to retain cycles.

Comment: that totally makes sense, i didn't notice the assign attribute. so i have to retain all my delegates myself all the time i guess. thanks!

Comment: @haag The "Lifetime Qualifiers" section of the "Transitioning to ARC" docs help in explaining this scenario a bit. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW4 I think the most important thing is to understand what the defaults are (w/o any qualifiers) -- that way, when you see them, you know "something is up". :-)

Comment: @haag Final thought -- in this example, you do have to be aware that the instance for the delegate should be retained. However, often times, you don't have to be bothered to care (but you should be aware). For example, people often make UITableView delgates (`delegate` and `datasource`) point to `self` in the context of the containing UITableViewController. The `delegate` and `datasource` are the controller instance, and the tableView is owned by the controller, so there is no need for "extra" retaining.

Comment: An argument to a method is retained when the method is entered, so the delegate object is not deallocated until _after_ `setDelegate:` has returned.

Comment: @greymouser - How does your solution work wrt ARC's lack of [precise lifetime semantics](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#precise-lifetime-semantics) for locals?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, delegate properties have weak connections, or should have weak connections. Thus, it's ARC releasing it (HPAppDelegate instance) after setDelegate because it's not used anymore, only locally by setDelegate method. You have to make a variable so ARC would know it will still be used.